# How to install the Heroku CLI without HomeBrew on MacOS

Tags: heroku-cli

I would like to install the Heroku CLI in my Macbook without using HomeBrew. Is there a way to do this? Perhaps by using a native command via terminal? Or some other way that does not depend on another bit of software? I have searched online but have not found a way to do so.

Note: I have had issues with HomeBrew so I no longer use it, and hope to continue installing without it. I also did a search on Stackoverflow, as well as check the suggested similar questions while composing this one.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else seeking answers: I just figured out how to install Heroku without Brew *or* using npm. Use the command below (it is in [Heroku's instructions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) page):

```
curl https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: I will try this method as soon as I get home!

Comment: Great--I hope it works. I thought you'd long found a solution since the question had been posted a month ago.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
npm install -g heroku
```

or else use:

```
sudo npm install -g heroku
```

Use it in the command line.